# How to get Heroku to ignore a failed import?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've got a project deployed on heroku using React and node, for which I'm importing a json file which contains various API keys (for firebase, AWS, etc.). In development, I simply do `import keys from './keys.json'`. However I was aware that wouldn't work in Heroku, so I set up the appropriate environment vars and used `process.env` to get them. Now though... the whole compilation/build of my project fails because Heroku can't find `keys.json` (since I don't deploy it, for apparent reasons). Is there any way to get it to ignore this one particular failure during build so it can go ahead and use the env vars?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the import in a conditional:

```
var keys = {}
if (!process.env['AWS_KEY']) {
    keys = require('./keys.json')['keys'];
}
```

This has the side effect of giving precedence to environment variables over a local file. If you want the file to have precedence instead, look at [`fs.existsSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) as your conditional (`fs.exists` could be used with some work).

Comment: This seems like it'd work, but it's telling me `'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level'`...

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately seems to have a related issue... `import in body of module; reorder to top`. Even though it's only the `if` statement between this import and my other ones.

Comment: I just tried it with `require` and it worked as expected. What error are you getting?

Comment: OK, I was able to get it working with `//eslint-disable import/first`. Didn't realise the linter was so zealous.

Comment: Actually, having deployed that to Heroku it still seems to be not reading `process.env.APIKEY` even though I've defined it as an env variable... since it still goes into that if statement and tries to load `keys.json`, and fails, and crashes. Not sure what's up with that but it did tell me that it's "starting the development server" instead of production... maybe that has something to do with it...